# MongoDB validation allowing everything

Tags: mongodb, validation

I'm starting to use MongoDB node driver and I can't get validation to work at all.

I created the following validation objects using query:

```js
validator: { $in: [
  { name: { $type: "string" } }
]}
```

And this JSON Schema:

```js
validator: {
 $jsonSchema: {
    bsonType: "object",
    required: ["name"],
    properties: {
      name: {
        bsonType: "string",
        description: "is required and must be a string"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then if I try to insert the following document with this structure `{name: 2}`, it gets added no failed validation whatsoever.

I've read the mongo and the node driver docs up and down regarding document validation and can't find a way to get this validated. I'm currently using Mongo version 3.6.7 and the node driver version 3.1.4, on an express server version 4.16.3.

This is the whole code:

```js
// create a single user
const createSingleUser = (client, db) => {
  db.collection("users").insertOne({
    name: 2
  }, (err, response) => {
    if (err) console.warn(err);
    console.log("new user added!!!!");
    client.close();
  }); // insert one
};

// create collection and add validator
const createUserCollection = client => {
  const MongoDriverData = client.db("MongoDriverData");
  // create the collection and add validation
  MongoDriverData.createCollection( "users", {
    validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
        bsonType: "object",
        required: ["name"],
        properties: {
          name: {
            bsonType: "string",
            description: "is required and must be a string"
          }
        }
      }
    }, // validator
    validationAction: "error"
  }, (err, results) => {
    console.log( "Collection created!!!" );
    // now insert a user
    createSingleUser(client, MongoDriverData);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks providing complete code. I tried your code with MongoDB 3.6.3 and the 3.1.4 node.js driver and I received a "Document failed validation" error.

Comment: I have tried your exact code and also receive a `Document failed validation`. However, the code subsequently printed `new user added!!!!`, but the `users` collection contains nothing. Is this the output you're seeing?

Comment: If that is the output you're seeing, please confirm that `{name: 2}` is not inserted into the collection. It might be also less confusing if you replace `if (err) console.warn(err)` in `createSingleUser` to `if(err) throw(err)` so the code will abort instead of continuing.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!! I'm not getting any errors, just the `new user added!!!` log and the user with a name of 2 is in the users collection. I'll change the log to a `throw` and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I created a repo with the whole code if you want to check it. Is not much yet because I haven't made the test files because this should be failing. https://github.com/rhernandog/mongodb-node-driver The relevant code is in the database folder https://github.com/rhernandog/mongodb-node-driver/blob/master/server/database/database_connection.js

Comment: @Rodrigo I don't see any difference between the code you posted & the one in the repo. Please check that you are running the right version of MongoDB by running `db.version()` in the `mongo` shell. JohnnyHK and I did try your code and we both found it resulted in the expected error and no document was inserted.

Comment: `db.version()` returns 3.6.7 and the node driver is 3.1.4

Comment: Hi, well at the end it turns out that the validation schema is not added when the collection is created. I added the validation via mongo shell and I got the errors. Of course the question is why??. I opened a ticket in the mongo driver in Jira to see what happens.

Comment: Why did it work for me and @KevinAdistambha then?

Comment: Silly me.... The collection was created without validation at first, then since the collection was already present, mongo didn't run the code to add the validation afterwards, seems reasonable right?. That's why after I added the validation via mongo shell it actually worked :S. Ahhh... never underestimate the good ol' human factor. Thanks @JohnnyHK and Kevin Adistambha  for your kindness and support!!!